# How to run a bash script except a selected line?

Tags: linux, bash

How to run a bash script with exception of any line as mentioned by its line number? For example if I want to run the entire script and avoid running the last line, Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the file before running it, for example with process substitution and sed:

```
bash <(sed '$d' script)
```

where `$d` is the sed command for "on the last line" (`$`), "delete the line" (`d`). `$` can be replaced by any line number you want to skip.

Applied: for a file `script` containing

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "second to last line"
echo "last line"
```

we would get

```
$ bash <(sed '$d' script)
second to last line
```

Comment: In the same way, commenting the required line may also be tried. For instance, to comment 5th line `sed '5 s/^/#/' <script_file.sh>`.